# Why setDropDownViewResource() and setAdapter() are not working?

Tags: android, arrays

Android Documentation says that this should be the way to populate an array but its giving error I can not figure out WHY???

> ```
> package com.example.android.gpacalculator;
>
>     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
>     import android.widget.Spinner;
>
>     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         }
>
>         Spinner grade1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grade1_spinner);
>         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> grade = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
>                 this,
>                 R.array.grade_array,
>                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>         // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
>         grade1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>     // Apply the adapter to the spinner
>         grade1.setAdapter(grade);
> ```

Comment: move everything into onCreate

Comment: Thanks BUT Still cannot use **setDropDownViewResource** method.     Only these meathods are there (setDropDownHorizontalOffset  setDropDownVerticalOffset  setDropDownWidth).

Comment: `setDropDownViewResource` is a method of `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: OK. Now what should I do here to make this code work.  I am a complete beginner.

Comment: In documentation this is given in the same way I used

Comment: @MutayyibAli - if you are a complete beginner, you should get a book or a step-by-step tutorial first. Documentation is not there to teach you programming, it has pretty minimal examples for experienced programmers to jump in quickly.

Comment: Yeah sure I understand.

Comment: @Davor - Can asking too many question result in cancellation of my account on stackoverflow,com?

Comment: @MutayyibAli - I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your spinner code to this:

> ```
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>
>         Spinner grade1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grade1_spinner);
>         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> grade = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
>                 this,
>                 R.array.grade_array,
>                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>         // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
>   grade.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>     // Apply the adapter to the spinner
>         grade1.setAdapter(grade); }
> ```

Comment: THANKS A LOT. I am new in android development. And I totally believe that asking questions is the best way to learn.

Comment: @MutayyibAli Glad to know that I was of help. Yes asking questions is the way to go, but as I see that you are new stackoverflow therefore make sure that you read stackoverflow guidelines on how to ask a question appropriately before asking more question. Good luck with android development.